# Bluetooth Magic Trackpad not recognized after sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

When I put my MacBook Pro (2011, 13") to sleep and wake it up again, the Magic Trackpad doesn't get recognized. I have to turn Bluetooth off and back on again to get the trackpad to work. It shows up in the Bluetooth menu at the top of the screen, but telling it to reconnect doesn't do the trick.

I have a USB keyboard, so I don't know if the same problem would be true of the keyboard.

Why might this be? Is there a way to have Bluetooth automatically restart when I wake the computer?

EDIT: I should mention that this has only happened since I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion last week.

Comment: Did u try to press the power button on the Magic Trackpad (then the green light will be on for a short while)?  Then you MBP will find it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, as well as powering the trackpad off entirely and turning it back on. No dice.

Comment: I have the same sleep issue mentioned above, on two different Mac Pro. One is running Lion, the other Snow Leopard. Coming out of sleep, the bluetooth system pref pane shows the trackpad connected, but the trackpad itself does nothing, i.e., no cursor movement or any on screen response. Same behavior on both Macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-pairing the trackpad. Go to `System Preferences` then `Trackpad` then `Setup Bluetooth trackpad...` Select the trackpad and then `Unpair`. Then select it again (using your built-in trackpad) and select `Pair`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the batteries again. I had the exact same issue with fairly new batteries that looked like Duracell but not Duracell. After trying a few recipes from Google search and calling Apple support to no avail, I thought I'd resort to the final technique of shaking and knocking the trackpad. That's when I heard a rattling noise inside the battery chamber. Sure enough, the batteries (Power Source AA from Costco) were about 1/2 mm shorter than the standard AA batteries, resulting in a loose connection. Can you believe that!?

The trackpad is working fine after replacing the batteries with Duracell (or other standard AA batteries). I hope this is the issue in your case.