# Magic Trackpad loses connection after sleep and doesn't connect again

Tags: sleep-wake, bluetooth, macos, magic-trackpad

I'm running on Sierra 10.12 my Magic Trackpad 2 is losing his connection after my Mac entered in sleep.

The most strange is that if I restart my Mac without settings intervention, the Trackpad will reconnect automatically without any problem...

PS : The issue was not resolved with this tread

[Bluetooth Magic Trackpad not recognized after sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/bluetooth-magic-trackpad-not-recognized-after-sleep)

Comment: Any chance there's another computer nearby that's hijacking the connection when your Mac goes to sleep?

Comment: Nop, my trackpad is only paired to my Personal and Work computer.. Actually I'm using it at work, so it's about 8km from the other one ^^

Comment: I'm experiencing the same with my Magic Trackpad 2.  My Apple Wireless Keyboard auto-connects but for some reason the Magic Trackpad doesn't.  Each time I want to use it I have to connect it manually.  Both are only paired with one machine and always in the same place.